# Copying a current value from one table to each new row on another table in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I am trying to build an access database that stores monthly billing data for a number of customers of a business.

Table 1 contains all the customer information including their 'current fee' which can change over time.

Each time a new record is created in Table 2 using a reference field from Table 1, I would like one field in Table 2 to be populated with the relevant 'current fee' - without overwriting any of the fee data in the other, previously created, records.

Is there a straightforward way to do this, or another way to solve the challenge?

Comment: Call GetCustomerFee(CustomerID, Customerdate)  wherever you need it.  add a code module with a public function GetCustomer.  GetCustomer wraps a query with some error handling.  Easiest query is to use the Dlookup function on the CustomerFees Table.   create a CustomerFees Table with columns CustomerFeeID, CustomerID, StartDate, EndDate, Amount.  Add A table of FeeTypes and a FeeTypeID column if you want.

Comment: Use form BeforeUpdate event to run code that pulls the 'current fee' and populates field.